# How to Use Freemarker Templates to Output JSON

Tags: java, json, templates, freemarker

I have an application that needs to process some data and output it as a JSON file. Rather than process everything manually, I thought I could use a templating library to structure the output. Freemarker seemed to offer what I was looking for, but I have run into a problem when dealing with lists.

The classes for my data model look like this:

```
public class Order {    
    public String orderNumber;
    public Date processed;
    public Boolean release; 
    public List<OrderLine> lines;       
}

public class OrderLine {
    public String unit;
    public Integer quantity;
    public String itemNumber;
}
```

The JSON output should look like:

```
{"OrderNo": "1055249", "OrderDate": "202103251951", "Release": true, "OrderLines": [
{"UnitOfMeasure": "EA", "Quantity": "1", "ItemNo": "764724473433"},
{"UnitOfMeasure": "EA", "Quantity": "1", "ItemNo": "764724810979"}
]}
```

Notice the list of OrderLines. I can put together a template for the other properties easily enough, but I have no idea how to handle a repeated element like an OrderLine. The built in **list** directive prints out each element but I need a comma separated list of values.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in freemarker without having to create a custom directive? If not, is there another templating library better suited to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: _Why_ use Freemarker to output JSON? (And did you search for something like "Java JSON library"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inbuilt loop vars](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html) to generate comma separated list of order lines. Please refer below example:

***Order.ftl***

```
<#import "OrderLine.ftl" as OrderLine>
{
    "OrderNo": "${order.orderNumber}",
    "OrderDate": "${order.processed?datetime}",
    "Release": ${order.release?c},
    "OrderLines": [
        <@OrderLine.OrderLine order.lines/>
    ]
}
```

***OrderLine.ftl***

```
<#macro OrderLine lines>
<#list lines as line>
        {
            "unit": "${line.unit}",
            "quantity": "${line.quantity}",
            "itemNumber": "${line.itemNumber}"
        }<#if line?is_last == false>,</#if>
</#list>
</#macro>
```

In above `ftl` I have used `?is_last` loop var to add `comma (,)` between two order line objects in the list.

Also, `<#if line?is_last == false>,</#if>` can be replaced with `<#sep>,</#sep>`. [check sep directive](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref_list_sep)

***FreemarkerService.java***

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;

public class FreemarkerService {

    private static final Configuration CONFIGURATION = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_0);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        OrderLine orderLine   = new OrderLine("EA", 1, "764724473433");
        OrderLine orderLine2  = new OrderLine("EA", 1, "764724810979");
        List<OrderLine> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add(orderLine);
        lines.add(orderLine2);

        Order order = new Order("1055249", new Date(), true, lines);

        Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<>();
        input.put("order", order);

        String json = generateJsonByTemplate("Order.ftl", input);

        System.out.println(json);
    }

    public static String generateJsonByTemplate(String templateName, Map<String, Object> input) throws Exception
    {
        String sourceCode = null;

        try
        {
            Template template   = CONFIGURATION.getTemplate(templateName);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            template.process(input, writer);
            sourceCode = writer.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Processing failed for template '" + templateName  + "' with error: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }

        return sourceCode;
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
{
    "OrderNo": "1055249",
    "OrderDate": "Aug 7, 2021 11:43:34 AM",
    "Release": true,
    "OrderLines": [
        {
            "unit": "EA",
            "quantity": "1",
            "itemNumber": "764724473433"
        },
        {
            "unit": "EA",
            "quantity": "1",
            "itemNumber": "764724810979"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `<#if line?is_last == false>,</#if>` can be replaced with `<#sep>,`. (Also, any condition like `something == false` can be replaced with `!something`.)

Comment: The <#sep> directive was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.32 you can write `"unit": ${line.unit?c}` instead of `"unit": "${line.unit}"`, because if the left-side of `?c` is a string, now instead of failing it quotes it. Thus you don't even have to know if the left-side is a number/boolean, which must not be quoted, or a string, which must be quoted, as it's automatic. Also, if the left-value is known to be missing/`null` sometimes, them `?cn` will handle that case by printing a `null` literal. (Also check out the `c_format` setting for best results, but by default string formatting is JSON compatible, so no worries.)